# rate of change proportional to the diffrence between itself and a fixed value $\frac{dy}{dx}=k(y-a)$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

So I have a question regarding exponential growth/decay problem formulated in my book.

In my book they say:

"Sometimes an exponential growth or decay problem will involve a quantity that changes at a rate proportional to the difference between itself and a fixed point:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=k(y-a)$

In this case, the change of dependent variable $u(t)=y(t)-a$ should be used to convert the differential equation to the standard form. Observe that $u(t)$ changes at the same rate as $y(t)(ie,\frac{du}{dy}=\frac{dy}{dt}) so it satisfies

$\frac{du}{dt}=ku$"

I am having a hard time grasping what they mean. And I would hope for somebody to expand on this notion.

More specifically how does $\frac{dy}{dx}=k(y-a)$ relate to $u(t)=y(t)-a$?

Comment: Can you write down the first order differential equation satisfied by u? You will recognise the form of this equation and be able to write down its general solution. Now what is y(t)? Remember that the derivative of any constant is zero.

Comment: Yup, @Dr.SonnhardGrauber just made me realise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since we have $$u(t)=y(t)-a$$ we get by differentiating with respect to $t$
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dt}$$ (since a is const.)
so we get
$$\frac{du(t)}{dt}=k\cdot u(t)$$